# For loop implementation with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I am doing anomaly/outlier detection on a data set that consists of entrance sensor data for a shopping mall, and there are several entrances. I have been able to test some outlier methods on isolated entrances, but I am struggling with implementing it for all of them.

Here is a snippet of the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"mall": ["Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1"],
                     "entrance": ["West", "West","West","West","West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "East", "East"],
                     "in": [132, 140, 163, 142, 133, 150, 240, 250, 233, 234, 2000, 222]})
```

One of the methods I use are the Z-score method, which detect outliers based on how many standard deviations the obervation is from the mean.

```
##Z-SCORE
out=[]
def Zscore_outlier(df):
    m = np.mean(df)
    sd = np.std(df)
    for i in df: 
        z = (i-m)/sd
        if np.abs(z) > 3: #(1=68.3%, 2=95.4%, 3=99.73%, 4=99.99%)
            out.append(i)
    print("Outliers:",out)
Zscore_outlier(df['in'])

#find rows of outliers
print(df[df['in'].isin(out)])

#count outliers
len(out)
```

I would want this to run on each entrance in one go, getting the output from the Z-score method for all entrances in one loop. I put the function outside the for loop and instead call it within. I use groupby on the *entrance* column. The output just gives me the last entrance of the loop, so entrance "East" twice. Here is my code:

```
def Zscore_outlier(df):
    out=[]
    m = np.mean(df)
    sd = np.std(df)
    for i in df: 
        z = (i-m)/sd
        if np.abs(z) > 3: #(1=68.3%, 2=95.4%, 3=99.73%, 4=99.99%)
            out.append(i)
    print("Outliers:",out)

by_label = df.groupby('entrance')
    
for name, group in by_label:
    Zscore_outlier(df['in'])

    #find rows of outliers
    print(df[df['in'].isin(out)])

    #count outliers
    len(out)
```

```
OUTPUT:
Outliers: [2000]
     mall entrance    in
10  Mall1     East  2000
Outliers: [2000]
     mall entrance    in
10  Mall1     East  2000
```

Comment: try using: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html to calculate mean and std for each group. That wil help you not to work with loops at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"mall": ["Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1", "Mall1"],
                     "entrance": ["West", "West","West","West","West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "East", "East"],
                     "in": [132, 140, 163, 142, 133, 150, 240, 250, 233, 234, 2000, 222]})




# solution itself
df['group_mean'] = df.groupby('entrance')['in'].transform(np.mean)
df['group_std'] = df.groupby('entrance')['in'].transform(np.std)
df['z'] = (df['in'] - df['group_mean']) / df['group_std']
# I've taken 2, as with 3 it is not an outlier
df['outlier'] = df['z'].abs() > 2

df[df['outlier'] == True]
```

[image: code output]